# "if" function for year and day

Tags: r, if-statement

In my dataset I have data for 2 years, so there are 730 entries. The problem is, that the column "Day of Year" has the form 1 to 365 for year 1 and the same for year 2.

I want the values in the column "Day of Year" to be 1 to 730.

My "newbie-function":

```
set$DoYnew = if (seq(set$Year==2002)) {set$DoY <- set$DoY+365}
```

doesn´t get me further. The error it gets is:

> In if (z < 0) { :>  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

The error is telling you that the clause to    `if` should be only a *single value*.
ie, either `TRUE` or `FALSE`, but *not* eg `c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)` .

So if trying to accomplish something like

```
if (c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))
  < DO SOMETHING WHEN TRUE >
  < DO SOMETHING DIFFERENT WHEN FALSE >
```

A basic `if` statement will not work.
The statement will just look at the ***first*** value (as the warning indicates).

For such situations, the statement to use is `ifelse` (as @Joran pointed out in his answer)

```
ifelse ( c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), 
  < DO SOMETHING WHEN TRUE > , 
  < DO SOMETHING DIFFERENT WHEN FALSE > )
```

or

```
set$DoYnew <- ifelse(set$Year == 2002,DoY + 365,DoY)
```

---

Additionally, if your data is in a data.frame, you can subset as needed:

```
 myDF$day[myDF$Year==2002] <- 365 + myDF$day[myDF$Year==2002]

 # or if using data.table: 

 myDT[year==2002, day := day + 365]
```

Comment: I hope it's ok, I just rolled my one liner into yours, since you put more effort into an explanation.

Comment: @Joran, of course.  I wanted to elaborate a bit since `if` is an interesting case of a lack of vectorization.